# Dot product of any point on plane and its normal

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d

I was trying to find the distance between a point and a 3D line with parametric equations.
On the web, I found a video detailling the steps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wznbg_aKOo

At 2:20, the person says that the dot-product of any point on the plane and its normal will always be equal.

I can't think of any proof for that! I could visualize it by visualizing the plane y=5 and the n trying dot-products with some points on the plane. It does work!

I can't find a way to prove it! Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_1, p_2$ be two points on the plane that has normal vector $n$.  Then the $v=p_1-p_2$ is perpendicular to $n$.  So $p_1 \cdot n = p_2\cdot n + (p_1-p_2) \cdot n = p_2\cdot n + 0$.

Comment: Eek! I couldn't follow you. Why is p2 + (p1-p2)n = p1 n ?

Comment: I missed an n, fixed now.

Comment: Great! Got it!!

Comment: Just a small correction (that doesn't really matter) if $p_1=p_2$ then $v=0$ which one might not really say is perpendicular to $n$, although the dot product $v\cdot n$ is still zero so the result still follows. You could also just say "Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be *distinct* points on the plane..."

Comment: Just to make sure, this does NOT mean that the dot product = 0 right?

Comment: No, just that $p_1\cdot n = p_2\cdot n$.

Comment: I don't understand how do you find a dot product between a point and a vector. Ok, assume we treat a point as a vector then other points would have different dot product values, wouldn't they?